# VS2013 & SQL Management Studio 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, ssms

What I'm currently working on is generating reports based on SQL data. I need to make a "back-up" copy of a SQL table. Normally, I would use Excel and its object library to do this, but there are compatibility issues with running programs that use it on the older computers in the workplace. As a result, I've had to use ReportViewer.

I noticed that there is a "Save Result As" feature when you query a table in SQL Management Studio 2008. Is there anyway to access that through VS2013 C#? Any references?

Comment: why do you want to back up the table in the first place? The accepted answer might be entirely incorrect depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: well I'm giving authorized users the privilege to delete the contents of a table. all i want to do is have that information in a spreadsheet, or report (so pdf, excel, word) in case they need to review the information. this is for an inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'SELECT * INTO'

Example:

```
SELECT * INTO LogBackup FROM dbo.Log
```

This will create a table called 'LogBackup' and copy in all the data from the 'Log' table.

Comment: Well that's true. I was hoping to find an answer more automated. I've already created a 'log' table in a sense, so what I really need to do is figure out a way to cue the 'Save Result As' feature in management studio from my web form. It's probably farfetched, but I'm just attempting to brainstorm more direct, efficient tasks.

Comment: If you need to be able to do this from the UI, then generating a CSV file and downloading the result might be the simplest option.

Comment: that's true as well. thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.